# Have jre7; JAR is jre6 compiled; can't run

Tags: netbeans, jar, java-7, backwards-compatibility, java-6

I built a JAR in NetBeans, setting the Source/Binary Format to JDK6.  So it's compiled to jre6.  I can use the JAR (outside the IDE), but if I send it to a machine with `jre7`, I have to alter the environment variable to get it to execute from the JAR.

1. Isn't Java backwards compatible?  Shouldn't this work without effort on jre7?  I am not doing -anything- fancy in this program.  It's a few kilobytes, couple hundred lines, import on some `Map` classes from `java.util`.
2. Is there a command-line option for java to use an older runtime, or an annotation to write in, to identify the class files as version 6?

Embarrassed I can't find specs to answer these questions.

Comment: Yes, Java is backwards compatible. The "old" jar should work. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: thanks for the formatting.  I checked again and ... it worked.  So umm.  Not reproducible.  I don't know?